# The "generator" of Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

It's since a bit of time that I'm wondering if to ask this or not, but eventually I will, hoping it's not a stupid question.

Let's write the Taylor Series for a general function $f(x)$ around $x_0$:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{f^{k}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k$$

Now let's call

$$f^{k}(x_0) = \frac{d^k}{dx^k} f(x)\big|_{x = x_0} = D^k_{x_o} f(x)$$

The Taylor Series expression now reads

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{D^k_{x_0}f(x)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k$$

Which I can write as

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(D_{x_0}\cdot (x-x_0))^k}{k!}\ f(x)$$

But wait: this is nothing but (operatorially speaking)

$$\large e^{(x-x_0)\ D_{x_0}}f(x)$$

That is

$$f(x_0) + (x-x_0)D_{x_0}f(x) + \frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)^2 D^2_{x_0}f(x) + \ldots$$

which brings me to conclude that Taylor Series is nothing but the series of the exponential of the derivative of a function around a point, applied to the initial function $f(x)$.

- Is that correct?
- Moreover, since I came to this result, what meaning (if any) could have to take another "generator" (I beg your pardon for the illicit use of this word) like $\sin$ or $\sinh$ or whatever?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you sure that $d^2f = (df)^2?$

Comment: Doesn't look correct to me. $\sin(\pi)=0$, but your formula would give $e^{\pi \cos(\pi)} = e^{-\pi} $

Comment: @R.Emery You are right, I made a mistake in the writing. Wait, I'm going to edit, but the question still holds.

Comment: Yep. If we define $Ef(x)$ to be $f(x+1)$ (that is, $E$ is the _shift operator_) then $e^D=E$. (Thus, $e^{hD}f=E^hf=f(x+h)$.)

Answer (score 1):

This can be given a sense in the theory of strongly continuous one parameter [semi-groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup) of bounded operators in Banach and Hilbert spaces. Consider the translation operator

$$(T_t f)(x) = f(x + t)$$

This is for example an isometry in $L^2({\mathbb R})$, but other spaces are possible. $T_t$ is a one parameter group of bounded operators, that is to say

$$T_t T_s = T_{t+s}\qquad T_0 = I$$

This group is generated by an unbounded closed operator with a dense domain, defined by
$$A f = \lim_\limits{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t}(T_t f - T_0 f)$$
when the limit exists. Here the limit exists if $f\in H^1({\mathbb R})$ and
$$A f = \frac{d }{d x} f$$
Then the group can be identified with the exponential of the unbounded generator, that is to say
$$T_t = e^{t A} = e^{t\frac{d}{d x}}$$
Or, the translation operator is the exponential of the derivation operator.

For suitably smooth function, you can then justify the Taylor series by expanding the exponential series
$$f(\cdot + t) = T_t f = \sum_0^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!} \left(\frac{d}{d x}\right)^k f$$